# Принять и редактировать. Описание правки

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок

Если при утверждении правки выбрать "Принять и улучшить", поменять только текст в поле `Описание`, то резолюция будет выставлена как ["Правка"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/87156), но в [историю изменений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/533284/revisions) описание не попадает вообще.

Хотелось бы понять: баг это или фича. И как вообще быть с правками, которые вроде бы полезны, с другой стороны имеют некорректное описание? Например, как по упомянутым ссылкам: `Попробуй так`.

Comment: Исправить описание предлагаемых правок нельзя однозначно, это будет приписывание человеку слов, которых он не писал. А писать поверх пустую правку с правильным описанием странно, ведь то описание никуда не делось. Так что... видимо, фича.

Comment: @Кнопкатык если это действительно фича, то надо статус ставить "принять", а не "правка". Раз уж правки по факту не было.

Comment: Ожидания нарушены, это да. Должно быть хотя бы предупреждение о том, что фактически это выходит не улучшение.

Comment: @Кнопкатык исправить описание принятой правки можно в исключительных случаях, например когда там оскорбления.

Comment: @NickVolynkin только если железной рукой модератора. Но интересный вопрос, что в этом случае делать "рядовым патрульным". Отклонять? Постить в чат? Тревогать вопрос?

Comment: @Кнопкатык тревогать лучше всего )