# Не сохраняется "описание" правки

Tags: поддержка, предложение

Ситуация: сделал правку в сообщении и добавил текст в поле "Описание", нажал <kbd>Сохранить изменения</kbd>. Подумал (в течение grace-period) и решил поправить описание, сохраняю, а не тут-то было. Т.к. тело правки не изменилось, то и новое описание не было подхвачено (а попросту - было утеряно). Данную ситуацию можно обойти, изменив одновременно и тело сообщения хотя бы на один символ перед сохранением, а потом ещё раз это тело вернуть назад. Но разве это правильно?

Вопрос имеет кое-что общее с [другим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3162/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8) моим вопросом, но ситуация несколько иная, т.к. я меняю описание своей собственной правки.

Comment: Это не дефект. Так задумано. Скорее, это прекрасное предложение ([аналогичное на англ.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79180/)).