# Способы обхода неоднозначных ограничений движка на Stack Overflow

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

Бывают ситуации, когда поведение сайта накладывает некоторые (неоднозначные) ограничения, которые при этом можно обойти путем пары дополнительных действий. Возможно эти ограничения стоит пересмотреть (отменить), или наоборот сделать так, чтобы нельзя было их обойти. Однако на текущий момент, о некоторых из них известно, и я предлагаю собрать в этой теме известные способы обхода тех или иных ситуаций (пока это не идет вразрез с правилами Сообщества).

Ниже перечислены ссылки на ответ по конкретной ситуации:

- [Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3393/176217)
- [Для общения в чате без явного разрешения необходимо не менее 20
  очков репутации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3433/176217)
- [Не сохраняется описание правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3822/176217)
- [Не удаляется метка из вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3816/176217)
- [Предотвратить закрытие вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4577/176217)
- [Изменить свой голос за сообщение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4585/176217)
- [Супер короткий комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4686/176217) и [ещё один](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12927/176217)
- [Отсутствует поиск по комментариям](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6651/181100)

Comment: Думаю, обходные тропы работают против ценностей сайта. Предлагаю использовать ограничения сайта, чтобы расти над собой. Лучше направить усилия на то, чтобы дополнить свою публикацию полезным материалом или дать несколько хороших ответов.

Comment: //todo: что делать, когда не принимается правка сверхкороткого сообщения, мигрировавшего с Хэшкода

Comment: //todo: заготовка ответа на щас-закроют-вопрос. И про последствия, если не улучшить сам вопрос.

Comment: @NickVolynkin что это за [tag:модераторский-произвол] тут происходит!?

Comment: @NickVolynkin да.

Answer (score 14):

> Для общения в чате без явного разрешения необходимо не менее 20 очков репутации.

В каждом сообществе StackExchange репутация не может быть меньше единицы. А поскольку чаты SE глобальные (кроме английского StackOverflow, там отдельные), и привилегии в них открываются по сумме репутации во всех сообществах SE, 20 очков можно набрать, присоединившись к 20 сообществам одним аккаунтом сети SE.

Comment: А что такое `явное разрешение`?

Comment: @alexolut особый список доступа к комнате, игнорирующий репутацию. Образуется, например, когда модератор (!) делает под сообщением чат. Или когда владелец комнаты или модератор кого-то явно туда добавляет.

Comment: Я так понимаю, из-за того, что есть три разных чата (SO, SE и Meta.SE) упомянутый подход не будет работать для SO и Meta.SE. Там просто нет нескольких разных сайтов.

Answer (score 11):

Если хочется изменить свой голос за сообщение (вопрос или ответ), но появляется баннер с текстом вида:

> Последний раз вы голосовали за этот вопрос Х минут назад. Сейчас ваш голос блокирован до тех пор, пока вопрос не будет отредактирован.

То при наличии достаточной репутации (2000+) для самостоятельной правки сообщения можно выполнить правку и сразу же её откатить. Например, добавить, а потом удалить один и тот же символ. Т.о. тело сообщения останется без изменений (хотя факт попытки правки будет зафиксирован в списке редакций), но вы получите возможность переголосовать.

Answer (score 10):

> Не сохраняется описание правки

Изменить тело сообщения хотя бы на один символ перед сохранением, а потом ещё раз это тело вернуть назад. ([отсюда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3391/176217))

Answer (score 9):

В процессе выпиливания метки [учебное-задание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) выявлен баг, заключающийся в невозможности снять метку с вопроса. Правка просто не сохранялась должным образом.

[Выяснилось](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32647702#32647702), что проблему можно решить добавлением любой новой (вр*е*менной) метки вместе с удалением старой, и последующим удалением этой временной метки.

Answer (score 8):

> Тело вопроса не отвечает стандартам качества

Если текст вопроса короткий — дублируем его несколько раз, проходим валидацию, а затем жмём на правку и удаляем дубликаты. ([отсюда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/628/176217))

Answer (score 7):

> Конкурсные вопросы невозможно закрыть обычным способом.
>
> — [Как устроена система конкурсов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3619/181100)

...так что чтобы **защитить вопрос от закрытия** на неделю, можно объявить на него конкурс.

Но нужно иметь в виду, что модераторы могут отменить любой конкурс.

Answer (score 6):

> Отсутствует поиск по комментариям

Вероятно, намеренно: не стоит оставлять только в комментариях то, что представляет ценность и может понадобиться в дальнейшем.

Но если очень-очень нужно, можно сделать [**поисковый запрос в Data Explorer**](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/775629/960188/search-posts-by-userid-comment-text) на вхождение подстроки в тексте комментария, без учёта регистра.

---

<sub>Оригинальный запрос взят [отсюда](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210112/318749), я только добавил `N` к шаблону (`N'%##CommentText##%'`), чтобы поддерживался русский язык. Иначе поисковые запросы на русском не дают результатов.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы добавить комментарий длиной менее 15 символов можно использовать ссылку куда-либо, вплоть до ссылки на сам комментарий. И обернуть "полезное" сообщение в эту ссылку:

> ```
> [Коротышка](ссылка)
> ```

Пример такого комментария можно найти под ответом.

Comment: [тыц](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3392/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow/4686#comment16591_4686)

Comment: Но ведь тогда это будет _ссылка_

Comment: @Grundy комментарий, содержащий ссылку, не перестаёт быть комментарием!

Comment: но он же становится уже ссылкой!

Comment: @Grundy [и?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3392/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow/4686?noredirect=1#comment16595_4686)

Comment: @alexolutttttt вот

Comment: А так? [](//void.null) - не прокатило :(

Comment: @Qwertiy не хулюганьте тут! :) Вот вам [песочница](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) для куличиков.

Comment: как заранее, до публикации комментария, можно узнать ссылку на него?

Comment: @mymedia завтра расскажу :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, завтра уже наступило.

Comment: @mymedia, [вот так](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3392/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow/4686#comment36249_4686)

Comment: @Grundy, у вас комментарий отредактированный

Comment: [А сейчас нет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3392/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow/4686#comment36258_4686)

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вариант, как написать очень короткий комментарий, при чём без ссылки на сам комментарий, так как это не очень удобно, ссылку на свой комментарий добавлять.  Идея [отсюда](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/392083?noredirect=1#comment1312231_392083):

```
Коротышка [​](https://google.com)
```

`[​](https://google.com)` отображаться не будет.

Пример в комментариях.

Comment: 12345 [​](https://google.com)

Comment: Оо, это я придумал.

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard у меня есть ссылка на ваш комментарий в песочнице, я соблюдаю лицензию =).

Comment: да да, всё ок :)

Comment: [​](https://google.com)

Answer (score -1):

Проблема: вопрос/ответ слишком короткий. Движок говорит, что надо ввести хотя бы 30 символов в тело сообщения.

Решение:

```
Короткий текст
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Идея из [песочницы](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359489/1346379):

[image: Пустой ответ]