# Как устроена система конкурсов?

Tags: поддержка, faq, конкурс

- Что представляет собой конкурс?
- Каково назначение вкладки «конкурсные»?
- Каким образом можно искать конкурсные вопросы?
- Как начать конкурс? Когда я могу начать конкурс?
- Можно ли использовать markdown-форматирование в объявлении о начале конкурса? Можно ли вообще редактировать это объявление?
- Какова длительность проведения конкурса?
- Как присудить победу в конкурсе?
- Могу ли я присудить победу в конкурсе за свой собственный ответ?
- Могу ли я присудить победу в конкурсе за уже имеющийся ответ?
- Если я объявлю конкурс в связи с вопросом другого участника, могу ли я выбрать автора вопроса победителем в этом конкурсе?
- После присуждения награды в конкурсе могу ли я отозвать ее или присудить другому  ответу?
- Как быть, если по истечении срока конкурса ответов на вопрос не поступило?
- Как быть, если я понимаю, что в ходе конкурса так и не получил ответа на мой вопрос?
- Что представляет собой автоматическое присуждение победы?
- Попадают ли награды в конкурсах под ограничение в 200 баллов репутации в день (возможность перечислить другим участникам не более 200 баллов рейтинга в день)?
- Как сочетается конкурс и статус вопроса «общий»?
- Могу ли я предложить повторный конкурс после окончания первого?
- Могу ли я увеличить вознаграждение за конкурс?
- Что произойдет, если конкурсный вопрос будет закрыт или удален?
- Почему я не могу голосовать за закрытие или перенос конкурсного вопроса?
- Что произойдет, если я удалю свою учетную запись, имея действующий конкурс?
- Сохранится ли полученная мной награда, если я удалю свой ответ?
- Будут ли мне возвращены баллы репутации, если вопрос, в котором я начал конкурс, и по которому уже была присуждена награда, будет удален или перенесен?
- Могу ли я аннулировать объявленный мною конкурс?
- Могу ли я разделить награду за мой конкурс между двумя или более участниками?
- Сколько уникальных конкурсов может быть у одного участника?

> См. также: «[Что такое конкурс? Как его начать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)» в справочном центре.

<sub>Перевод публикации «[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/274323)».</sub>

Answer (score 14):

> #### Источники: официальный [раздел FAQ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) и [публикации](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/) [блога](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/).
>
> #### См. также официальную [страницу привилегий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties).

#### Что представляет собой конкурс?

Награда – это особый вид вознаграждения для автора лучшего ответа в конкурсном вопросе. Эта функциональность разработана для того, чтобы мотивировать участников отвечать на сложные вопросы, а также, чтобы повысить качество ответов, премируя самые выдающиеся.

Награда в конкурсе присуждаются за счет репутации участника, начавшего конкурс. Награда может варьироваться от 50 до 500 баллов репутации с инкрементальным шагом в 50 баллов.

**Примечание:** Если вы начинаете конкурс в вопросе, на который *вы* уже ответили, [ваш минимальный призовой взнос должен составить 100 баллов репутации](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack/64826#64826) (а не 50).

Для того чтобы начать конкурс, быть автором вопроса необязательно. В одном вопросе может быть только один действующий конкурс; каждый участник может иметь не более 3 действующих конкурсов одновременно.

По состоянию на июнь 2010 [система наград в конкурсе отделена от механизма принятия ответов](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/).

---

#### Каково назначение вкладки «конкурсные»?

#### Каким образом можно искать конкурсные вопросы?

Вопросы, в которых данный момент объявлен конкурс, в списке вопросов отмечаются особой пиктограммой и отображаются на вкладке «конкурсные». Вопросы на этой вкладке отсортированы по времени, оставшимся до окончания конкурсов – чем ближе дата окончания конкурса, тем выше вопрос в списке.

---

#### Как начать конкурс? Когда я могу начать конкурс?

Конкурс может быть объявлен в вопросе, заданным не менее 2 дней назад.

Для того чтобы начать конкурс, щелкните нажмите ссылку <kbd>начать конкурс</kbd> внизу выбранного вопроса. Откроется панель конкурса. Используя выпадающий список, выберите награды – от 50 до 500 баллов с шагом в 50 баллов.

Для того чтобы объявить конкурс, вы должны иметь минимум 75 баллов репутации; при этом ваша репутация также не должна быть меньше устанавливаемой награды.

При объявлении награды соответствующая сумма баллов будет изъята из вашей репутации сразу *после начала конкурса* (а не по его завершению).

---

#### Можно ли использовать markdown-форматирование в объявлении о начале конкурса? Можно ли редактировать это объявление?

Публикация об открытии конкурса [допускает разметку markdown с ограничениями аналогичными комментариям](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks). Разрешено следующее:

*курсив* и **полужирное** начертание,
   встроенный `код в обратных одинарных кавычках`
   и [ссылки](http://example.com).

Вы [не сможете изменить](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text) сохраненное сообщение, поэтому перед сохранением проверяйте его дважды.

---

#### Какова длительность проведения конкурса?

1 неделя = 7 дней.

По состоянию на июнь 2011 г. [авторы конкурсов могут принимать решение о победителе не позднее 24 часов с момента его окончания](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remaining/74037#74037) (в течение т. н. периода отсрочки): это предусмотрено для того, чтобы авторы могли оценить ответы, размещенные перед самым окончанием конкурса. В течение периода отсрочки в списке вопросов конкурсный вопрос будет отображаться как обычный, без указания того, что в нем проводился конкурс –  [см.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272475).

Учтите, что если ответ на ваш вопрос отсутствует либо вы ответили на вопрос сами, период отсрочки будет составлять все те же 24 часа. Ответы, опубликованные в течение этого периода времени также могут получить награду в конкурсе.

---

#### Как присудить победу в конкурсе?

Победу в конкурсе можно присудить в течение 24 часов с момента его начала. Победителем может стать любой ответ – даже тот, который уже имеет одну или более конкурсных наград. Это также касается наград назначенных вами за ответы в предыдущем конкурсе.

Для того чтобы присудить награду в конкурсе, щелкните на кнопке <kbd>+50</kbd> (или другой, соответствующей награде в конкурсе) слева от ответа, который вы хотели бы выбрать победителем.

[image: Подсказка по механизму присуждения конкурсной награды]

---

#### Могу ли я присудить победу в конкурсе своему собственному ответу?

Нет. Ранее это было возможно, [но в данный момент эта функциональность отключена](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97802).
Увеличения репутации не произойдет, а сумма вознаграждения будет отображаться как **+0**, «этому ответу была присуждена награда в 0 баллов».

---

#### Могу ли я присудить победу в конкурсе за уже имеющийся в системе ответ?

Да, вы можете присудить награду уже существующему ответу. Таким образом, участники получают возможность отметить особенно удачные ответы большим числом баллов.

Чтобы указать, что ваша награда уходит уже существующему ответу, в вопросе «Почему вы начинаете этот конкурс?» выберите вариант «Наградить существующий ответ».

> [image: Наградить существующий ответ]

Помните, что награду можно *присудить* только после *минимального срока в 24 часа* с момента начала конкурса.

---

#### Если я объявлю конкурс в вопросе другого участника, могу ли я выбрать автора вопроса победителем в этом конкурсе?

Да, награда может быть присуждена любому ответу, кроме ответа автора конкурса.

Это означает, что если вы объявите конкурс в вопросе другого участника, а автор этого конкурсного вопроса предложит ответ, вы можете присудить награду этому ответу.

---

#### После присуждения награды в конкурсе могу ли я отозвать ее или присудить другому  ответу?

Нет, награда присуждается раз и навсегда – автора конкурса предупреждают об этом в момент присуждения им награды.

---

#### Как быть, если по истечении конкурсного срока ответов на вопрос так и не поступило?

Если после окончания конкурсного срока ответы на вопрос отсутствуют, награда не присуждается; на вкладке «конкурсные» вопрос больше не отображается.

Конкурсы можно интерпретировать как обмен баллами репутации для повышения видимости вопроса и увеличения мотивации отвечающих. Конкурс *не* гарантирует ответа и в случае его отсутствия **конкурсные баллы назад не перечисляются**.

---

#### Как быть, если я понимаю, что в ходе конкурса так и не получил ответа на мой вопрос?

#### Что представляет собой автоматическое награждение?

Если организатор конкурса не определил победителя лично, награда может присуждаться автоматически – [приблизительно](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147576/bounty-not-awarded-after-the-end-of-the-grace-period/147577#147577) через 24 часа после окончания конкурса.

Если организатор конкурса в течение конкурсного срока принял один из ответов, данных в течение конкурсного периода, награда присуждается этому ответу. Ответам, принятым до начала конкурсного периода награда автоматически не присуждается.

В противном случае, если ответы на вопрос были получены, но не один из них не отмечен верным то, *половину* награды получает ответ с наивысшим рейтингом. Критерии, которым должны соответствовать ответы, чтобы принять участие в конкурсе:

- Ответ должен быть дан *после* начала конкурса.
- Ответ должен иметь минимальный рейтинг +2.
- Ответ не должен быть дан автором конкурса.

Если два или более ответа, участвующих в конкурсе, имеют один и тот же рейтинг, награда присуждается более раннему из них.

Если ни одно из этих условий не соблюдено, награда не присуждается. Соответствующая сумма баллов автору конкурса *не* возвращается.

---

#### Попадают ли награды под ограничение на 200 баллов репутации в день (возможность перечислить другим участником не более 200 баллов в день)?

Нет, награды в конкурсах под это ограничение не попадают.

---

#### Как сочетается конкурс и статус вопроса «общий»?

Общие сообщения не влияют на механизм конкурсов. Когда вы присуждаете награду общему ответу, бонус к репутации получает участник, который опубликовал первоначальную версию ответа.

---

#### Могу ли я начать повторный конкурс после окончания первого?

#### Могу ли я увеличить вознаграждение за конкурс?

Вы можете предложить столько конкурсов, сколько пожелаете. Однако одновременно допускается проведение только одного конкурса по каждому вопросу. При этом участник может иметь [не более 3 активных конкурсов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more/104813#104813) одновременно.

Учтите, что если вы объявляете несколько конкурсов в одном и том же вопросе, [вам нужно будет каждый раз как минимум удваивать награду](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639). Иначе говоря, если ваш первый конкурс был эквивалентен 50 баллам репутации, второй конкурс в том же вопросе должен гарантировать вознаграждение как минимум в 100 баллов, третий – минимум 200 баллов и т.п. Если вы уже объявили награду в конкурсе в 250 баллов и более, вы все же можете объявлять конкурсы, эквивалентные 500 (максимальная сумма) – пока у вас есть желание и необходимая репутация. «Правило удваивания» касается только конкурсов, объявляемых одним и тем же участником в одном и том же вопросе.

---

#### Что произойдет, если конкурсный вопрос будет закрыт или удален?

#### Почему я не могу голосовать за закрытие или перенос конкурсного вопроса?

Конкурсные вопросы невозможно закрыть обычным способом.

Однако [модераторы](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) могут вернуть автору конкурса награду, что позволит закрыть вопрос, перенести его или удалить как любой другой ([источник](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103)).

---

#### Что произойдет, если я удалю свою учетную запись, имея действующий конкурс?

Права на конкурс перейдут [Духу сообщества](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user), награда, как обычно, в конце конкурсного периода будет отдана победителю
([источник](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89614/152859)).

---

#### Сохранится ли награда, если я удалю свой ответ?

При удалении ответа, победившего в конкурсе, вся репутация за этот ответ, включая призовые баллы, аннулируется. Соответствующие изменения репутации становятся заметными [примерно в течение 5 минут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work). Автору конкурса награда не возвращается.

---

#### Будут ли мне компенсированы баллы репутации, если вопрос, в котором я объявил конкурс, и по которому уже была присуждена награда, будет удален или перенесен?

Да. Вы заметите это не сразу (как это происходит с другими изменениями репутации), но эти баллы вам вернут
([источник](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172556/152859)).
Если вопрос будет удален и потом восстановлен, либо его перенос будет отклонен, баллы репутации снова будут вычтены.

---

#### Могу ли я аннулировать объявленный мною конкурс?

Нет. Начав конкурс, вы не можете его отменить.

Если вы считаете, что у вас возникли чрезвычайные обстоятельства, отметьте вопрос сигналом тревоги, чтобы привлечь внимание модератора, и объясните ситуацию.

---

#### Могу ли я разделить награду между двумя или более участниками?

Нет. Несколько победителей может быть только у вопроса, имеющего несколько конкурсов.

---

#### Сколько уникальных конкурсов может быть у одного участника?

Не более трех. Чтобы объявить еще один конкурс вы должны выбрать победителя хотя бы в одном из текущих.

---