# Присуждение награды за конкурсный вопрос с неправильным ответом

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-так-задумано, конкурс

Мною был создан конкурсный вопрос, и на него поступил ответ, который оказался некорректным.
Я отметил вопрос "Минусом", поставил тревогу "Не является ответом" и даже сам автор ответа в комментариях подтвердил, что его совет не помог.

Однако поскольку его ответ получил 4 плюса, по итогам конкурса награда была присуждена ему.

Почему у автора вопроса отсутствует решающий голос в такой ситуации? Корректно ли такое поведение конкурсных вопросов?

Пример ситуации о которой я говорю:
[IE убирает границы ячеек при печати нескольких страниц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561416/ie-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86)

Я читал правила конкурсных вопросов, и понимаю как они работают сейчас. Мой вопрос скорее теоретический и предлагает обсудить улучшения для данной системы.

Comment: *поставил тревогу "Не является ответом"* -- [зря](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3568/181100). Тревоги не предназначены для обозначения неправильности ответа.

Comment: Почему Вы считаете, что у автора должен быть решающий голос в такой ситуации?

Comment: Про тревогу понял. Спасибо. Некорректно понял её суть. Про решающий голос: только автор может понять помог ему ответ или нет в большинстве случаев, и то что люди не прочитав до конца все комментарии к ответу влепили плюс не вникнув в суть вопроса - не должно быть решающим фактором для награды. Эта система хороша когда автор вопроса не реагирует на ответы, но в случае когда автор явно даёт понять, что ответ неверный - на мой взгляд награда выдаваться не должна.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Забавная ситуация получилась. Пришло время изложить...

## Догадки и домыслы

> Конкурсы можно интерпретировать как обмен баллами репутации для повышения видимости вопроса и увеличения мотивации отвечающих. Конкурс не гарантирует ответа и в случае его отсутствия конкурсные баллы назад не перечисляются.
>
> — [Как устроена система конкурсов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3619/181100)

У конкурса есть чёткий *дедлайн*. По его наступлении нужно выбрать, кому достанется репутация. В данной ситуации "кому отдать награду" выбирать просто не пришлось за наличием всего одного варианта.

Если бы мы не были скованы существующей системой, у нас было бы четыре варианта:

- Продлить конкурс

  - И бесплатно дать вопросу ещё внимания?
  - ...или не бесплатно? Тогда можно начать ещё один конкурс с новым призом и существующая система позволяет это сделать.
- Вернуть репутацию

  - Внимание привлечено за определённую долю репутации, сделка состоялась. Оснований для возврата нет.
- **Присвоить награду тому, кто всё-таки ответил**

  - Автоматика присваивает награду самому "хорошему" ответу по следующим (упрощённым) критериям: либо на нём есть **галочка**, либо у него рейтинг выше всех (но не меньше +2).
  - По-хорошему, *неправильный ответ не должен был оказаться с рейтингом +2 или выше*, получается, что **система голосования дала сбой по человеческому фактору**.
  - А ещё неправильные ответы (с точки зрения их авторов) неплохо бы **удалять**. Если ответ оказался неверным, но всё равно содержит ценную информацию, скорее всего, вопрос надо уточнить.
- **Выкинуть репутацию в никуда**

  - Например, отменив конкурс, что штатными средствами сделать нельзя, можно только если модератор решит, что это в конкретной ситуации допустимо ([пруф](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3619/181100)). Можно попытаться поговорить с модераторами, раз уж неправильность ответа не отрицает даже его автор.

Comment: Согласен с вашими доводами. И понимаю что в данном случай получился сбой по человеческому фактору. Поэтому мне кажется что порог в 2 балла слишком низок, поскольку фактически получается, что мнение двух невнимательных людей важнее чем мнение автора вопроса подробно изучающего проблему и автора ответа, который понял что он не прав.

Comment: @ВикторЖариков Вы можете поставить минус, и тогда 2 превращается уже в 3. А какое число Вам кажется было бы более подходящим?

Comment: Мне кажется такая система должна работать если автор вопроса не реагирует на ответы. А когда реагирует, и явно показывает что ответ не удовлетворительный - награда не должна присуждаться никому.

Comment: @ВикторЖариков возможно, в этом и есть смысл. Нечто противоположное галочке. Но такие ситуации очень редки, возможно, в таких случаях надо ткнуть модераторов отменить конкурс.

Comment: @D-side т.е. как раз таки тревога, которую ткнул ТС.

Comment: @alexolut это другая тревога.

Comment: @D-side с точки зрения ТС это действительно не является ответом. Поэтому не погружаясь в детали описания этого типа тревоги всё выглядит логично. При этом подробности модератор может почерпнуть из комментариев под ответом. Хотя бесспорно правильнее всю дополнительную информацию по тревоге приложить именно к самой тревоге (т.е. уже придется выбрать иной тип), чтобы проверяющий не терял время на ее сбор, читая различные комменты.

Comment: @alexolut не надо путать "неправильный ответ" и "не ответ".

Comment: Изначально я ткнул в "другая причина тревоги" и там расписал ситуацию. Тревогу отклонили. После чего я для очистки совести нажал в "не является ответом". Возможно я что то не понял в формулировке данной тревоги, но на мой взгляд заведомо неправильный ответ не вносит полезной информации в обсуждение проблемы, а значит его "Возможно следует удалить" (Как указано в формулировке тревоги). Кнопка обратная по значению "галочке" - хороший вариант. Она бы решила такую проблему. И по моему, такая ситуация не редкая, учитывая что для "Голосования за" нужно очень мало репутации, а значит и компетентности

Comment: Я ни в коем случае не утверждаю, что такое имело место быть в моей ситуации (в моей наоборот человек попытался помочь), но этим (гипотетически) можно злоупотребить. Оставить какой нибудь расплывчатый ответ из серии "Попробуйте выключить и включить", так чтобы он не попадал под модерацию "Не является ответом". Попросить двух некомпетентных людей поставить плюс. И вот тебе 50-500 баллов из ниоткуда. С точки зрения правил площадки - не придраться. С точки зрения полезности и развития ресурса - плохо.

Comment: @ВикторЖариков у нас есть определённые проблемы с формулировками, а у модераторов есть почти шаблонная причина отклонения тревог: "тревоги не должны использоваться для обозначения фактически некорректных или неправильных ответов". Я основываюсь на этом, одну мою тревогу так уже отклонили, но это не единственный случай, о котором я знаю. Тревоги не предназначены даже для тривиальных ответов, которые 100%-но не помогут, но предлагают хоть какое-то (пусть даже не работающее) решение. Отсеивать такие -- задача минусов.

Comment: В любом случае теме уже поставили метку "Статус-Так-Задумано". Поэтому видимо дальше обсуждать смысла нет

Comment: @ВикторЖариков в общем, да, т. к. решение вроде как есть: попросить модераторов отменить конкурс. Жаль, что никто из них так и не рассказал о деталях таких просьб.