# Как назначить награду за вопрос в мобильной версии?

Tags: поддержка, конкурс, мобильная-версия

Как назначить награду за вопрос в мобильной версии? Ну кааак это сделать? Не нашёл я этой кнопки.

Comment: В мобильной версии *сайта* или в мобильном приложении?

Comment: @NickVolynkin допускаю, что ТС не читает описания к [правкам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/5201/revisions) и меткам.

Comment: @alexolut возможно. Кстати, у [meta-tag:мобильное-приложение] описания не было. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin зато было у [tag:мобильная-версия]. Может быть есть смысл добавить синоним [tag:мобильный-сайт]. Так будет более очевидно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так же как и в полнофункциональной версии сайта - нажать соответствующую ссылку:

> [image: мобильная версия]

Для дополнительного чтения: [Как устроена система конкурсов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3618/176217)