# Срочный конкурс

Tags: обсуждение

У меня был [очень срочный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726325/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-sass-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B), но на него так и не кто не ответил. Как мне назначить конкурс сейчас, или придется ждать еще до завтра? это очень срочно.

Answer (score 5):

Согласно правилам сайта, назначить конкурс можно лишь по истечении двух дней с момента публикации.

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на справку по системе конкурсов: [Как устроена система конкурсов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3618/)