# Односторонняя политика конкурса

Tags: обсуждение, правила, конкурс

Недавно прошел конкурс и автор не дополнил информацию и получил ответ, как заменить элемент. Однако отказался показать код

[Sugarcrm CE 6.5 : Как заменить html subpanel-и на свой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/732070/sugarcrm-ce-6-5-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-subpanel-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9/735587#735587)

И награда до сих пор не выплачена.
Однако в такой же ситуации, когда человек дал общий ответ и не дал конкретики, с меня сняли баллы.

[Ошибка при добавление поля на событие bitrix 16.5?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643562/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-bitrix-16-5)

Я хочу, чтобы если вы поменяли политику в ту сторону, что за общие ответы не давать баллы конкурсные, верните тогда мои тоже. Если же правила остались прежними, верните  заслуженную карму.

Comment: судя по всему в момент завершения конкурса ответ не подходил под требования для автоматической выдачи.

Comment: Тогда почему не был заблокирован вопрос.

Comment: Кроме того в такой же ситуации автоматика сработала.

Comment: Почему должен был быть заблокирован вопрос? Был назначен конкурс, был дан ответ, когда конкурс закончился автор не выбрал правильный ответ, и автоматика сама определила сделать победителем единственный ответ либо нет

Comment: Вопрос общий из серии что делать и не соответствует правилам сайта.

Comment: То что он в конкурсе не значит что ему бан не разрешен.

Comment: Кстати ответ не является поводом для не бана.

Comment: О каком _бане_ идет речь?

Comment: Я в теме, почему мой тогда выдали.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67937/discussion-between-grundy-and-vasilyuk-dmitry).

Comment: @VasilyukDmitry про бан ничего не ответил вам, потому что не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. «Бан» — это блокировка пользователя или закрытие конкретного вопроса?

Answer (score 8):

Давайте посмотрим на временную шкалу.

### [Случай 1: Sugarcrm CE 6.5 : Как заменить html subpanel-и на свой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/732070/timeline)

1. Автор вопроса объявил конкурс.
2. Срок конкурса истек.
3. Поскольку до окончания конкурса автор не принял ни один ответ и не выбрал победителя, применяются [автоматические критерии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3618):

   - Ответ должен быть дан после начала конкурса.
   - Ответ должен иметь минимальный рейтинг +2.
   - Ответ не должен быть дан автором конкурса.
4. Имеющийся единственный ответ не удовлетворяет второму требованию. *Дух сообщества♦* закрывает конкурс без награды

   > Closed, non-winning bounty for question Id = 732070

### [Случай 2: Ошибка при добавление поля на событие bitrix 16.5?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/643607/timeline)

1. Автор вопроса объявил конкурс.
2. Срок конкурса истек.
3. Автор вопроса выбрал победителя

   > 3 апр в 6:57 окончание конкурса Vasilyuk Dmitry   Winning bounty for question Id = 643562
4. Автор вопроса принял свой ответ.

---

Как видим, ситуации отличаются. Никто не отменял конкурс вручную из-за слишком "общего" ответа.

Кроме того, не забывайте, что назначение конкурсной награды не гарантирует получение хорошего/правильного ответа. По сути, вы платите сотню репутации за  рекламу в специальном разделе, привлекающем участников к вашему вопросу. Поэтому при отмене конкурса или отсутствии победителей репутация не возвращается обратно.

Answer (score 7):

Вы потратили 1/5 часть полученной вами репутации на конкурсы. Похоже, что вы рассматриваете репутацию как виртуальные деньги, как инструмент, а не как способ измерения ЧСВ. Это разумный и достойный уважения подход.

Сочувствую, что вы потратили репутацию на конкурс, но не получили ответ. К сожалению, периодически такое случается. Помню вопрос, автор которого [дважды открывал конкурсы на 500 репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/440193/timeline) и не получил ни одного ответа.

#### Конкурс — это инвестиция

Конкурс — это инструмент с высокой потенциальной доходностью, но и высоким риском. Вы *сразу и навсегда* тратите какое-то количество репутации, а в ответ получаете *шанс* на то, что вам дадут подходящий ответ.

Сравните это с инвестицией в стартап. Он может взлететь и принести вам значительную прибыль, но может и прогореть. Вернуть деньги из такого стартапа никак нельзя — они потрачены на попытку взлететь.

#### Если разрешить отмену конкурса, ей будут злоупотреблять

- Если подходящий ответ дан, есть соблазн отменить конкурс и приберечь репутацию.
- Даже если не появилось новых ответов, к вопросу привлечено внимание, а вместе с ним — плюсы и репутация. Можно будет назначить конкурс на огромную сумму на свой вопрос или ответ, набрать репутацию, а потом отменить конкурс.

#### Конкурсы полностью автоматизированы

Вручную вы только начинаете конкурс и выдаёте награду. Если конкурс кончился, а вы не выдали награду, то решение принимает система.
К сожалению, она не может оценить качество ответов самостоятельно.
Поэтому она опирается на голоса участников и отдает половину награды лучшему из ответов, данных с начала конкурса и имеющих рейтинг 2 или больше.

> [Как устроена система конкурсов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3618/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)

Возможно, квалифицированный и беспристрастный арбитр мог бы принимать более оптимальное решение в спорных ситуациях. Но такому арбитру нужно платить зарплату реальными деньгами, а его работа никогда не принесет компании Stack Exchange прибыль.

---

<sup>Автор открыл на этом сайте 31 конкурс на 2100 репутации (из них в одном награду выдал Дух сообщества) и выиграл шесть конкурсов. Автору можно верить.</sup>