# Получение знаков за вопросы/ответы

Tags: поддержка

**Промоутер**, **Инвестор**, **Благодетель**, **Альтруист** - как получить эти знаки?

Для этого надо участвовать в конкурсе и предлагать награду за вопрос?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Описание достаточно подробное для них:

[Промоутер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/46/promoter) - открыть конкурс для своего вопроса ([Благодетель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/47/benefactor) - вручили награду).
[Инвестор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/45/investor) - открыть конкурс для чужого вопроса ([Альтруист](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/48/altruist) - вручили награду).

Comment: А как открыть конкурс для чужого вопроса? Что-то не вижу такой кнопки. Или это только начиная с определенного уровня репутации?

Comment: [75 репутации нужно для этой привилегии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). Причины отсутствия кнопки описаны по ссылке.

Comment: И еще - вручили награду - что это значит? Это значит, что я открываю конкурс, дожидаюсь ответа и принимаю его - и это будет вручением? А что с вопросом чужим, если там не вручат награду? Или я сам должен буду перенаправить дополнительные баллы репутации за хороший ответ?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3618/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2?rq=1

Comment: @Jenssen, награду вручает тот, кто конкурс начал. Не принимаешь ответ, а именно награду вручаешь.