# Механика премии за неначисленный конкурс

Tags: поддержка, репутация, конкурс

Вопрос по механике начисления конкурсных балов.
Я начислил 50 балов репутации за вопрос. Ясно, они с меня списались.
Вот картинка с вопросом, которую я вижу.

> [image: скриншот]

Срок конкурса истек, ответов по-прежнему ни одного.
Назначать премию некому, но как мне их вернуть себе?
Ведь результат не достигнут  -  значит мой престиж должен вернуться мне.
Что скажете?
Я конечно могу вписать какой то ответ и сам себе назначить. Но мне кажется это извращением.  Как и "нарушение закона сохранения энергии". В одном месте убавилось, и нигде не прибавилось :-)

Comment: `и сам себе назначить` а так разве можно? :)

Comment: `как мне их вернуть себе?` - никак. на то это и конкурс, вы добровольно расстаетесь с репутацией. А ответы конкурс не гарантирует

Comment: Когда вы принимаете свой собственный ответ на свой вопрос вам репутацию не добавляется

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - а как же закон сохранения престижа?
я вынул 50 единиц ценности и объявил о готовности передать их "победителю". Победитель не пришел  - внимание вопрос - не логично ли вернуть 50 единиц мне?
Так как умных не нашлось?
Вопрос о механике. Я отдал 50 чтобы выполнить "квест" - назначить 50 за ответ на чужой вопрос.
Если 50 не вернулось - то разумно засчитать квест? 
Логично?
Квест называется "Альтруист" а не "транжира" ))

Comment: @VasylKolomiets я поставил 1000 руб на 6 черное, 10000руб на 9 красное и 100000руб на зеро - ничего из этого не выпало - не логично ли мне вернуть мои 111000руб?

Comment: читайте справку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty ..... там даже жирным выделено **Награда всегда назначается вперед и не изымается обратно ни при каких обстоятельствах.**.....то, что вас это не устраивает - увы, но это ваши заботы. вас предупреждали  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  амогли бы вы ответить ваш комментарий как ответ?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets в справке есть еще информация *Награда не гарантирует ответ, а потраченная репутация не возвращается, если на конкурсный вопрос никто не ответит*

Comment: @АлексейШиманский )
Я не оспариваю правила тем более что я этого не прочел.
Однако я вижу эту картину так:
Я поставил 100 на красное, 100 на черное и 100 на зеро.
А крупье не пришел.
Нельзя ли мне выдать жетон о том что я поставил 100?
Ответ - нет.
Я не заработал "Альтруист"??
Давайте смотреть системненько на ситуацию.
Или вы хотите сказать что  в Альтруисте описана моя ситуация :-)
Впрочем - мне все понятно.
Последнее. По поводу места размещения вопроса. Я бы стал искать МЕТу, если бы не нашел здесь тег stackoverflow.
Хорошего дня!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как устроена система конкурсов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3618/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2) -- там обсуждается и ваш вопрос тоже, почти напрямую.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets кратко: назначая конкурс вы не делаете ставку, а платите репутацией за привлечение внимания к вопросу. Более полно вы можете почитать по приведенным чуть выше ссылкам.

Comment: Мне кажется Вы путаете 2 знака, Альтруист и Инвестор. Инвестора заработали, Альтруиста пока нет.