# Нельзя закрыть конкурсный вопрос

Tags: обсуждение

Жаль что нельзя закрыть конкурсный вопрос, а иногда так хочется. Это часть -  зона ответственности самой платформы? или же можно было бы например закрывать за 25 голосов вместо 5-ти? Или это может сделать модератор?

---

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Как сделать кнопки для прокрутки контента?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960283/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)

[Горизонтальная прокрутка работает колесиком мышки. Как сделать аналог свайпом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/960023/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC)

---

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как устроена система конкурсов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3618/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2). Пункт "Почему я не могу голосовать за закрытие или перенос конкурсного вопроса?"

Comment: @αλεχολυτ спасибо, сразу не смог найти

Comment: В этой помойке чёрт ногу сломит :)