# Как лучше: внести огромные исправления в старый вопрос или задать новый, а старый удалить?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, вопросы, удаление-вопросов

Я задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1482831/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-jar-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-jre), но через некоторое время понял, что он не очень понятен и другие пользователи меня не понимают, даже пытались закрыть его как дубликат(коим он не является, мой вопрос немного о другом) Я хочу внести правки в него, но правки довольно серьёзные: как минимум половину я перепишу. Стоит ли мне внести огромные правки в старый вопрос или задать новый и удалить старый?

Comment: Если создадите новый, то он поднимется, и его увидят больше людей

Comment: @nomnoms12 но ведь после редактирования он тоже поднимется

Comment: @Danis Да, но новый ещё будет отображаться в "Новых вопросах"

Comment: большие изменения можно вносить в вопрос, если на него не было ответов, Нет нужды удалять старый вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соглашусь здесь со [мнением](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12282/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B#comment53147_12282) опального модератора, что при наличии ответов (к тому же с голосами "за" и галочкой принятия), что глобальная переформулировка не является допустимой. Удалить вопрос с положительными ответами система тоже не даст (насколько я помню). Поэтому правильным вариантом тут будет задать новый вопрос, желательно со ссылкой на прежний, чтобы сохранить контекст. А старый оставить как есть.

Для привлечения внимания к вопросу принятым на сайте способом является объявление [конкурса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3618/176217). Регулярные поднятия вопроса путём незначительных правок не поощряются на сайте.