# Альтернативные "стандарты качества" для вопросов на Мете

Tags: предложение, качество-вопроса

Довольно часто при заполнении баг-репорта по работе сайта сталкиваюсь с появлением баннера о не соответствии вопроса стандартам качества. Вот такого:

[image: стандарты качества]

Проблема не очень страшна для тех, кто знает [как её обойти](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3392/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-stack-overflow), хотя и является раздражающим моментом (иначе бы я об этом не писал). А вот кого-то другого, впервые сталкивающегося с подобным уведомлением, может оттолкнуть вообще от желания оставлять баг-репорт, и т.о. факт выявления ошибки и уведомления о ней заинтересованных лиц будет отложен, и скорость эволюции сайта замедлится.

Предлагаю упростить "стандарты качества" (по факту являющиеся "стандартами количества") для вопросов на Мете.