# Почему начать конкурс можно только через два дня?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, конкурс

"Вы можете предложить вознаграждение за ответ на вопрос, заданный более двух дней назад".

Почему начать конкурс можно только через два дня после того, как вопрос был создан? Зачем необходимо это ограничение по времени?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Я думаю, причина тут примерно та же, что и с заявлением в ЗАГС. Дать время подумать, стоит ли оно того, ведь вознаграждение не возвращается обратно, независимо от факта получения ответа.

Нет особой причины жертвовать репутацией раньше времени. Если проблема простая - она скорее всего будет решена достаточно быстро (можно обойтись без конкурса). Если же проблема существенно сложнее, то написание ответа, и даже сам факт осознания этой сложности другими участниками, скорее всего, потребует некоторого времени.

Учитывая, что конкурс может длиться до семи дней, разрешение о назначении его сразу же после создания вопроса вряд ли существенно ускорит появление подходящего ответа.

Так же не стоит забывать, что конкурсный вопрос имеет некоторые привилегии, в частности он [не может быть закрыт обычным способом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4577/176217). И если допустить создание конкурса сразу, плохой вопрос может мозолить глаз и требовать дополнительной работы от модератора. Этого хотелось бы избежать.

Comment: Да, вполне логично )

Comment: Полностью не согласен с ответом! Единственно верная причина, это не позволить сделать из форума биржу труда на которой расплачиваются балами. Мне нужно что-то сделать, а время нет и тут я раз и 2000 баллов. Согласитесь, сделали бы.

Comment: @OlmerDale во-первых, не каждый имеет возможность пожертвовать столько репы; во-вторых, ответ не гарантирован, а потеря репы - обязательна (биржа предполагает более честный обмен); в-третьих, существующие пороги 50 - 500; ну и в-четвертых, сложная задача не может быть решена мгновенно, в любом случае придется ждать. Я думаю, этот список можно продолжить. Но при прочих равных, отмена двухдневного ожидания до начала конкурса просто будет приводить к более частой потере репы, а не её заработку.

Comment: Найдутся люди которые репу будут поднимать по несколько тысяч за неделю. А за 500 останется ждать, в то время как за бесплатно вообще не ответят. Несколько раз видел как откровенно наглые просьбы были отвергнуты, а затем получали ответы после назначения награды. Хотя для меня вообще дико представить что кто-то не хочет отвечать просто так, но хочет за циферки на мониторе..

Comment: @OlmerDale Вы по-моему уже о чём-то другом говорите. Текущий вопрос о возможных причинах двухдневной отсрочки, а не о лимитах по репе. Когда конкурс в активной фазе, наличие отсрочки уже не имеет никакого значения. И я не могу сказать, что за каждый конкурсный вопрос идёт ожесточённая борьба дабы получить "заветную" репу.

Comment: @OlmerDale Вы лучше опубликуйте свой ответ, раз категорически с моим не согласны.

Comment: @OlmerDale: И правда, альтернативные ответы лучше давать в виде альтернативных ответов, а не комментариев.

Comment: Иногда бывают узкоспециализированные вопросы, которые гугл не занает, а привлечь внимание к вопросу для быстрого ответа надо.  В придачу, вряд ли участник, который задаст мусорный вопрос, наберёт хотя бы 75 баллов. Так что беспокоиться модерам не о чем.

Comment: @val ситуации, когда закрываются вопросы, заданные участниками с репутацией существенно >75 не такая уж и редкость.

Answer (score 1):

Перенёс сюда все свои доводы из аналогичного обсуждения, чтобы они не потерялись в истории:

#### Видимость вопроса и эффективность конкурса в первые дни

В течении первых двух дней вопрос и так увидит большинство активных пользователей, отслеживающих интересующие вас метки.
Соответственно, **Ваш вопрос** и так получит **достаточно внимания**.

#### Мне нужно срочно и быстро

Если Вы хотите объявить конкурс, для того чтобы Вам срочно и быстро решили задачу, то скорее всего Вы ошиблись ресурсом.
**Срочно и быстро** можно сделать **на фрилансе.**
*Если подобные поползновения не пресекать, то у ресурса есть все шансы превратиться в биржу.*

#### Лишняя конкуренция

Как говорилось выше - в первые дни Ваш вопрос и так получите достаточно внимания.
Если к этому еще добавить конкурс, то это будет не очень честно по
отношению к вопросам, которые были заданы ранее и уже вышли из зоны
видимости большинства пользователей.
Зачем **отнимать** внимание и **конкурировать** с вопросами, которые находятся в **худшем положении** и **не могут** получить внимание другим способом?

#### Небольшая стоимость

Всем хочется получить ответ на вопрос прямо здесь и сейчас.
Размер минимальной награды очень маленький.

Если с таким размером дать возможность всем назначать конкурсы, то на этой вкладке может начаться настоящая вакханалия и свалка из-за чего данная вкладка может **потерять весь свой смысл**.

Регулировать это можно размером минимальной награды.
Но тогда пользователи с небольшим количеством репутации могут лишиться возможности получить ответы на свои воросы.

Выбирая между возможностью сразу же публиковать конкурс и демократичной ценой - лучше последнее, как мне кажется.

#### Злоупотребление

Ну и стоит понимать, что при возможности публиковать конкурс сразу могут появиться желающие данных механизмом злоупотреблять (Особенно с текущей ценой)... речь идет о рекламе, спаме, желающих расплатиться за работу репутацией и пр.

#### Время на проверку вопроса

Также если мне не изменяет память - конкурс сложнее закрыть силами рядовых участников.
Поэтому нужно какое-то время на его проверку силами участников сообщества.