# Как дать награду за принятый ответ?

Tags: поддержка, конкурс

Хочу дать награду за ответ, но он уже принят и такой опции не нахожу. Такое вообще возможно? Глупо ведь, если предложить награду можно только, если ни один ответ еще не принят.

Comment: надо начать конкурс и затем выбрать нужный ответ

Comment: @Grundy так там нет кнопки "начать конкурс"

Comment: Если не трудно, то добавьте ссылку на ответ, за который вы хотите дать вознаграждение. Может быть вы просто не заметили кнопку?

Answer (score 3):

**Можно ли это сделать?**

Это можно сделать, но только **если вопрос был задан более 48 часов назад**. За это есть даже специальный знак: [image: альтурист]

**Как это сделать?**

Это можно сделать, если вопросу более 48 часов. Давайте проверим: любой вопрос, на который есть ответ и он старше 48 часов. Например, [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496488/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-shed). Смотрим под вопрос (**именно под вопрос, а не под ответ!!!**) и видим:
[image: что мы видим]

**Почему у вас не получается это сделать?**

Есть два варианта:

1. Вопрос был задан менее 48 часов назад;
2. Вы ищете кнопку "начать конкурс" под ответом, а не под вопросом;

Comment: А, про 48 часов не знал.

Comment: @Эникейщик как раз об этом [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5119/176217)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну глупо на самом деле. Т.е. в общем случае понятно, но я то хочу не открыть конкурс, а наградить человека уже давшего ответ. Зачем же мне для этого ждать два дня?! Через два дня я уже и забуду об этом или забуду о чем был вопрос, как сейчас, например.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну отлично, теперь еще сутки ждать, прежде чем могу награду вручить 

Comment: @Эникейщик желание наградить существующий ответ ничем фактически не подкреплено. Несмотря на выбор "хочу наградить имеющийся ответ" вполне можно по итогам выдать награду новому ответу. Поэтому условия и сохраняются, кмк. Ну и вдруг кто даст ещё более крутой ответ пока конкурс висит? Это добавляет чуть больше геймофикации в систему, и становится интересней по-моему.

Comment: @Эникейщик добавьте ответ в закладки. Это поможет вам не забыть об ответе ну и может быть случиться чудо - раз ваш ответ настолько хорош, что вы его хотите наградить, то может  25 человек всё-таки добавят его в закладки и автор заработает **серебряный** знак [избранный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/461/favorite-answer), на русском SO его ещё никто не получил =).