# Продолжение обсуждения в чате для участников, которые там не могут писать

Tags: предложение, репутация, комментарии, чат

Иногда у ответов, которые я даю, появляется очень много комментариев от автора вопроса, и тогда сообщество автоматически предлагает мне продолжить обсуждение в чате. Однако писать в чате могут не все участники (только с репутацией выше 20), и как правило у людей, задающих вопросы, столь высокой репутации нет. Стоит ли системе предлагать перенести обсуждение в чат, если всё-равно я не смогу там ничего обсуждать с автором вопроса?

Comment: В настройках доступа чата можно разрешить писать туда конкретному участнику даже если репутация не тянет. То есть сами создаете чат, добавляете новичка в настройках доступа и все ок. Куда тыкать точно не скажу, но это здесь уже точно обсуждалось)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУкрываться Что-то даже если тыкнуть туда, куда Вы сказали, участник с низкой репутацией всё-равно не может писать.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Поступил отзыв, что добавить пользователя с недостаточным уровнем репутации всё равно нельзя. Есть вероятность, что большая часть этого ответа неверна и предоставлять такой доступ могут только модераторы.
>
> Удалить этот ответ я не могу, т. к. он принят, поэтому пока оставляю предупреждение и обновлю, как только поступят надёжные сведения.

---

## Сможете.

Сделайте чат (*сами*, это важно, объясню ниже), **скопируйте ссылку на профиль пользователя**, зайдите в чат и идите по такому маршруту:

> room▼ | control access | **Explicit write access** | ...
>
> ... <kbd>add user</kbd> | **profile URL** | *<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>* | <kbd>grant write access</kbd>

Так вы явно предоставите пользователю возможность общаться в комнате, даже если для других комнат пользователю не хватает репутации.

#### Но имейте в виду...

Эта возможность доступна только **владельцам комнаты** и это сработает только если вы создадите комнату сами, а не дождётесь предложения системы.

В созданных *системой* комнатах владельцев нет и вышеописанную процедуру могут выполнить только модераторы.

---

*Какая-то связанная с этим автоматика существует, но у меня скорее воспоминания, чём точная информация. По-моему, система и так не предлагает перейти в чат, если одному из собеседников не хватает для этого репутации. Но комнатам, создаваемым **модераторами** из бесед в комментариях (с комментарием вроде "Комментарии не предназначены для расширенных бесед") участникам предоставляется доступ автоматически.*

---

*А 20 единиц репутации набрать, на самом деле, [можно и скучным механическим методом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3433/181100).*

Comment: а еще стоит дополнить, что репутация берется _по всем_ сайтам сети, и возможность писать может появиться, если зарегистрироваться в 20 сайтах :-D

Comment: @Grundy кстати да. Добавил ссылку на соответствующий совет.

Comment: Получается, автор заблуждается, говоря, что появляется автоматическая ссылка для участников, которые не могут в чат?

Comment: @alexolut у меня нет точной информации по этому вопросу.

Comment: Я как автор вопроса могу сказать, что бывала (и не раз) такая ситуация: пишу много комментариев к вопросу или к своему ответу, и тут внезапно появляется предложение перенести обсуждение в чат. Я начинал писать в чат, но ответов никаких не было, автор мотивировал это тем, что у него нет привилегии такой (да и рейтинг у него был очень низким). Возможно сейчас уже такого нет и никто с таким не столкнётся, в любом случае теперь я знаю, что в чате можно на своё усмотрение выбирать участников и репутацию, необходимую для общения в чате, можно легко набрать без ответов на вопросы.

Comment: Такой способ не работает для обычных пользователей. Некоторое время назад хотел так сделать, но система все равно не дала доступ к комнате участнику с репутацией меньше, чем 20 сообщений.

Comment: @D-side Спустя столько времени проблема есть до сих пор. Как же обсудить в чате что-то с тем у кого репутации маловато?

Comment: @RomanPodymov в конце ответа есть ссылка на один глупый, но работающий хак, позволяющий без содержательных действий набрать репутации на доступ к чатам SE.

Comment: @D-side Хорошо, сейчас попробуем получить 20 очков.

Comment: "*Есть вероятность, что большая часть этого ответа неверна и предоставлять такой доступ могут только модераторы.*" - Слишком поздно, но на самом деле верна. Просто предоставить доступ можно только пользователю, который хотя бы один раз заходил на chat.stackexchange.com. Скорее всего из-за этого не получалось.