# Проблемы с перемещением дискуссии в чат

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, чат

Я знаю что здесь не приветствуется расширенная дискуссия в комментариях. У меня на данный момент идет дискуссия с одним товарищем [Добавление объекта при нажатии на кнопку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882304/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83/882305#882305)
и почему-то он не может переместить нас в чат. Реплик уже куча, и не хотелось бы заваливать сайт и дальше, насколько я понял отвечающий не может переместить дискуссию в чат?? Помогите пожалуйста, потому-что у меня нету кнопки для перемещения.

Comment: участнику с репутацией меньше 20 нечего делать в чате: он не может отвечать. Поэтому система и не предлагает.

Comment: плохо, я думал может глюк какой, а я так понял не могу переместить нас? это только ТС может?

Comment: Могут модераторы.

Comment: Посмотри в блоке связанные вопросы: [1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5184/186999), [2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/591/186999) и еще [вот сюда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3392/186999) можно глянуть