# Условный дефект при добавлении комментария

Tags: дефект, предложение, комментарии, ссылки

На данном сайте комментарий имеет ограниченное количество символов. Как я понимаю, так сделали для того, чтобы ограничить максимальную высоту блока комментария для хорошего дизайна.

Теперь сам (условно) **баг**:

При добавлении комментария учитывается вся длина текста комментария, и ***длина адреса гиперссылки*** тоже, а ведь она не отображается, хотя порой адреса ссылок бывают слишком длинными для комментария.

Для того, чтобы не быть голословным, приведу пример комментария, который хотелось бы отобразить:

> @USERX вы знаете, ваш цикл у меня выполняется за 1-5 миллисекунд. Знаете, проблема может быть не в этом цикле, а в отображении на форме ваших 2000 точек (или других объектов, которые отображаются и которых много). Формы очень долго отображают большое количество объектов. Вот [мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635436/wpf-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80) по оптимизации кода. Он похож на ваш.

Как видите, отображаемый текст комментария будет допустимой длины, в то время как длина предварительного текста комментария превышает допустимую.

В связи с чем хочу внести предложение по изменению расчета максимальной длины для комментария, без учета адреса ссылки гиперссылки.

Comment: Ну так неспроста появились всякие укоротители ссылок. В данном случае более короткую ссылку можно было бы получить через `поделиться` под вопросом. Там ещё и `id` юзера можно вырезать. Ну и если размер самой ссылки не учитывать, то [вот это вот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4686/176217) перестанет работать. А я не хочу ответ переписывать или удалять.

Comment: @alexolut Извините, я не замечал, что на данном сайте есть функция "поделиться" с генерацией короткой ссылки. Скажите, а почему ваш пример ссылки перестанет работать, если не учитывать длину гиперссылки?

Comment: Потому что минимальный размер комментария 15 символов.

Comment: Аа, я подумал, вы мне про саму ссылку говорите, а не про то, что по ее адресу находится :) Да, не будет. Но ведь ограничение для минимальной длины комментариев не зря сделали... зачем тогда писать комментарий длиной меньше 15, если его сам движок запрещает?

Comment: Там вся тема про обход таких ограничений :) В общем, мутить какой-то более хитрый подсчёт длины (как это недавно сделал твиттер) тут не будут. Собственно, [вот](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8382/339911).

Comment: *Как я понимаю, так сделали для того, чтобы ограничить максимальную высоту блока комментария для хорошего дизайна.* -- это, кстати, голословно. Я сходу могу привести другой мотив: чтобы в комментариях не разводили слишком содержательных дискуссий, т. к. все содержательные детали должны уходить в вопросы и ответы, а не оставаться в комментариях к ним.

Comment: @alexolut, _"Ну так неспроста появились всякие укоротители ссылок"_ - на SO они запрещены и комментарии с ними не постятся ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy https://goo.gl/a4yPY8

Comment: @alexolut, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313621/4928642

Comment: @Qwertiy к счастью, этот изврат только на SOen сделали (:

Comment: Если длина ссылки не будет учитываться, то обязательно найдутся мамкины кул-хацкеры, которые попытаются хакнуть so, запихнув в ссылку гигабайтный текст.